# Why JIT compilers can't be used to produce binary?

Tags: java, jit

JIT compilers are used to convert java byte-code into native machine language. And as far as I know, there is no program which can directly convert java byte-code into binary file such as .exe files. So why JIT compilers can't be used to produce binary from the byte-code?

Comment: JIT is just a part of it.. you need to understand why a JVM is required.. it is much more than just compilation.. There is memory management , thread control etc

Comment: They can't out of the box, probably because: 1) JIT's are part of the Java binary/distribution 2) JIT's don't convert the entire program to native code, only the hotspots.

Comment: Because JITs only compile relevant parts "just in time" - at the time the code is actually executing. That means you needed to have a normal JVM up and running to actually get to that point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert JIT to EXE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347204/convert-jit-to-exe)

Comment: *"So why JIT compilers can't be used to produce binary from the byte-code?"*  Why would you want to?  There is no point to it.

Comment: Yeah.. I got it. I thought JIT alone is responsible for this compilation process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JIT compiler, compiles the code dynamically.

- It generates different code for different flavours of CPU.
- It generates different code for different memory models, e.g. For tyhe 64-bit JVM, if the maximum heap size is < 4 GB, < 24 GB, < 32 GB or more, you will produce different code in each case.
- It will re-compile code as classes are loaded and unloaded.
- It will re-optimise code based on how it is used. e.g. if a flag which used to be off is not on and visa-versa.

A static compiler cannot do these things.

Answer (score 2):

JIT = Just In Time. An *.exe is compiled way before of execution. `</nitpick>` ;)

As others said, there is more to a JVM than just compiling bytecode to native machine code. However, these parts of a JVM can be put into a native library ("dll").

There is at least one project to generate native binaries out of java code: GCJ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcj). I don't know how good it is and whether there is a windows version available. There might also be other Java-to-native compilers out there.

Comment: There used to be half a dozen such compilers a decade ago: TowerJ, JOVE, NaturalBridge, all gone by now beside GCJ and Excelsior JET.

Answer (score 1):

The aims of JITs and compilers are normally different, I think that is the main reason.

That said, the [Maxine VM](http://labs.oracle.com/projects/maxine/) contains a JIT written in Java that is used to compile the entire VM itself and the output is written to a so-called bootimage, essentially being a binary. However, even this binary needs an executable, called loader, to start.

So, there is at least one example for a JIT that is used to produce a binary,
but normally, the aims of a JIT do simply not include producing a binary.

Answer (score 0):

Jit is a re compiler, so for any particular system platform, it compiles the bytecode into the particular system code. So we cannot directly use the Jit to turn Java-byte code into binary executables.

When the jit produces binary code, its binary format will not support another platform. The main usage of a Jit-compiler is fast compilation as a second compiler for Java. Therefore Jit can't produce binaries from Java bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Java Runtime is capable of storing the results of dynamic bytecode to native code compilation in its shared data cache and sharing it between JVMs ([prooflink](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc%2Fdiag%2Funderstanding%2Faot.html)).